# Ignore multiple definitions for a function in PhpStorm code inspections

Tags: phpstorm

I have a complex PHP project that contains two definitions for a function `foo`. One of those is in a vendor library, and I never use it, the other one I use a lot. The implementation in the vendor library throws an Exception, the correct implementation does not. Now anytime I write a function that calls foo(), PhpStorm's code inspections say I should declare a @throws \Execption in the caller's PhpDoc. I'd like to suppress that warning in this case, and maybe tell PhpStorm that I will *never* use the function in the vendor library.

I've experimented with Scopes, but couldn't make that work - I can prevent PhpStorm from reporting warnings in the vendor files, but not from analyzing them for symbols used in my own code.

Comment: Try right clicking on such unwanted file and mark it as Plain Text -- this way the file should not be processed at all (will affect all other stuff in that file as well though). You cannot tell IDE "use definition from this file and ignore them from other places".

Comment: That's sort of what I want - to tell PhpStorm that I don't care about the code in this file at all. Cannot find an option to mark the file as Plain Text in the right-click menu, though.

Comment: It may not be available to Libraries then (files that are treated as non-project code)... Try this then (not sure if it will work, but worth checking): 1) Mark any project file as Plain Text (just to have config file created); 2) Close IDE; 3) Locate `plainTextFiles.xml` in IDE settings folder (on Windows that would typically be `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2019.3\config\options`; 4) Edit that file -- replace entry from #1 with full path to that "unwanted" file; 5) Save file and launch IDE -- see if it made any difference.

Comment: You still should be able to mark them as plain text: https://i.gyazo.com/60e7d502ca7047e8cf6e06596e509371.png

Comment: Thanks for the visual! I was right-clicking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/** @noinspection PhpDocMissingThrowsInspection */`
or `/** @noinspection ALL */` (for disable all inspections) at the top of method *foo()*

Comment: Since the offending implementation of foo() is not my code, but managed by composer, I can't actually edit it. There should be an easier way to say "This file? Pretend it's not part of my project, please".

Comment: so you say that you try in  Appearance & Scopers > Scopes; add new scope and exclude file that contain foo method?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and that only stops inspecting the file that contains the bad function. The warning comes from the file that is *calling* foo(), not the one that is *defining* it.